# Difference between vserver and Linux Container

Tags: linux, docker, container

Can anyone explain me difference between linux containers and vserver?   I mean containers managed by docker.  I tried to read in the internet, but I have a problems with understanding it.  Can anyone help me grasp difference, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean containers managed by docker.

Not really.

> LXC (Linux Containers) combines the kernel's cgroups and support for
>   isolated namespaces to provide an isolated environment for
>   applications. Docker can also use LXC as one of its execution drivers,
>   enabling image management and providing deployment services. [1]

---

**LXC (Linux Containers)** and **Linux-VServer** are two different technologies, but they have the common goal in achieving OS-level virtualization technologies on Linux.

---

**Linux-VServer**

is a virtual private server implementation that was created by adding operating system-level virtualization capabilities to the Linux kernel. [2]

**Means** host *kernel must be patched*.

---

**LXC (Linux Containers)**

is an operating-system-level virtualization method for running multiple isolated Linux systems (containers) on a control host using a single Linux kernel.[1]

**Means** that **LXC** utilizes existing the cgroups functionality provided by the linux kernel that allows limitation and prioritization of resources (CPU, memory, block I/O, network, etc.)

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux-VServer